# Long database query time due to number of while loops

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am using the following code to get data from my DB and display it on my website. I have noticed that because I use too many "`while()`" loops my website is loading very slowly. I know the DB I have is badly constructed, but that was the best I could do at the moment.

I have a DB named "properties" which contains 10+ columns:
`id`, `title`, `country`, `location2`, `location3`, `location4`, `location5`, `location6` etc

What I want to do is: when I browse for example, table `country = 'spain'` it contains locations in table "location2"(example `ibiza`), next I browse `"location2" = 'ibiza'`` which contains locations from location3 and so on.

Is it possible to do this using just a single `while()`?

```
<?php
$select_loc2 = "SELECT DISTINCT `location2` FROM `properties` WHERE ".$between_price." `country` = '".ucfirst($location)."'";

$locs2 = mysql_query("$select_loc2") 
or die(mysql_error());  

while($loc2 = mysql_fetch_array( $locs2 )) {
if(!empty($loc2['location2']))
$locb = str_replace("'", "\'", $loc2['location2']);
{$link2 = '<a href="browse.php?location='.urlencode(strtolower($locb)).'&guests='.$_GET['guests'].'&min_price='.$_GET['min_price'].'&max_price='.$_GET['max_price'].'">'.$loc2['location2'].'</a>';
echo '<span style="display: inline-block; width:33%;">'.$link2.'</span>';
}
}

$select_loc3 = "SELECT DISTINCT `location3` FROM `properties` WHERE ".$between_price." `location2` = '".ucfirst($location)."'";

$locs3 = mysql_query("$select_loc3") 
or die(mysql_error());  

while($loc3 = mysql_fetch_array( $locs3 )) {
if(!empty($loc3['location3'])){
$locb = str_replace("'", "\'", $loc3['location3']);

$link3 = '<a href="browse.php?location='.urlencode(strtolower($locb)).'&guests='.$_GET['guests'].'&min_price='.$_GET['min_price'].'&max_price='.$_GET['max_price'].'">'.$loc3['location3'].'</a>';
    echo '<span style="display: inline-block; width:33%;">'.$link3.'</span>';
}}

$select_loc4 = "SELECT DISTINCT `location4` FROM `properties` WHERE ".$between_price." `location3` = '".ucfirst($location)."'";

$locs4 = mysql_query("$select_loc4") 
or die(mysql_error());  

while($loc4 = mysql_fetch_array( $locs4 )) {
if(!empty($loc4['location4'])){
$locb = str_replace("'", "\'", $loc4['location4']);

$link4 = '<a href="browse.php?location='.urlencode(strtolower($locb)).'&guests='.$_GET['guests'].'&min_price='.$_GET['min_price'].'&max_price='.$_GET['max_price'].'">'.$loc4['location4'].'</a>';
    echo '<span style="display: inline-block; width:33%;">'.$link4.'</span>';
}}


$select_loc5 = "SELECT DISTINCT `location5` FROM `properties` WHERE ".$between_price." `location4` = '".ucfirst($location)."'";

$locs5 = mysql_query("$select_loc5") 
or die(mysql_error());  

while($loc5 = mysql_fetch_array( $locs5 )) {
if(!empty($loc5['location5'])){
$locb = str_replace("'", "\'", $loc5['location5']);

$link5 = '<a href="browse.php?location='.urlencode(strtolower($locb)).'&guests='.$_GET['guests'].'&min_price='.$_GET['min_price'].'&max_price='.$_GET['max_price'].'">'.$loc5['location5'].'</a>';
    echo '<span style="display: inline-block; width:33%;">'.$link5.'</span>';
}}


$select_loc6 = "SELECT DISTINCT `location6` FROM `properties` WHERE ".$between_price." `location5` = '".ucfirst($location)."'";

$locs6 = mysql_query("$select_loc6") 
or die(mysql_error());  

while($loc6 = mysql_fetch_array( $locs6 )) {
if(!empty($loc6['location6'])){
$locb = str_replace("'", "\'", $loc6['location6']);

$link6 = '<a href="browse.php?location='.urlencode(strtolower($locb)).'&guests='.$_GET['guests'].'&min_price='.$_GET['min_price'].'&max_price='.$_GET['max_price'].'">'.$loc6['location6'].'</a>';
    echo '<span style="display: inline-block; width:33%;">'.$link6.'</span>';
}}
?>
```

Comment: Use Joins for your query.

Comment: Your script is ready to get injected. Be aware of that. Use PDO. Also the way you build your URIs is not secure. Too  much place for manipulation.

Comment: Nana, I am having trouble with JOIN, can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: Lots of lovely cargo-cult programming in there too. `"$var"` is rather pointless...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are concerned with doing this properly but a `union all` would probably speed things up:

```
$select_loc = "
    SELECT `location2` as `location`, '2' as `number`
      FROM `properties`
     WHERE ".$between_price." `country` = '".ucfirst($location)."'
     UNION
    SELECT `location3` as `location`, '3' as `number`
      FROM `properties`
     WHERE ".$between_price." `location2` = '".ucfirst($location)."'
";

// debug SQL
echo $select_loc.'<br>';

$locs = mysql_query($select_loc) or die(mysql_error());  

while($loc = mysql_fetch_array( $locs )) {
    echo $loc['number'].' : '.$locl['location'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Code doesn't seem to work, I am trying to find the error. Thanks!

Comment: @Kev please see my update with the "debug SQL" comment. If you can then post the output of `echo $select_loc.'<br>';`

Comment: Ok, I corrected the code from $locl['location'] to $loc['location'] but when I echo the resuts it displays all the locations from locations2 and locations3, it should only display the locations2 here, and if I click one of this locations it should display locations from locations3 and so on until locations6. Can you help with this?

Comment: @Kev Yes, I only showed how to union 2 and 3, did you figure out the rest? I think one of the main causes for the slowness is going to be the `DISTINCT` clause. I recommend trying your query with my latest update using just `union` without the `all`. Also, 20k rows is not a lot of rows, maybe you can add an index on the location2, location3, etc columns to speed things up.

Comment: @MoneyZeus I figured out the rest of the code and it works fine but now, after I removed the DISTINCT I realized that the query takes that long because without DISTINCT it displays like 50k times the same location because each row in the DB contains one of those locations and that's why it takes so long to load. Is there another option I can use instead of DISTINCT that will have the same effect?

Comment: Yes, your query works fine now but it still takes a long time to load. I guess the normal query should return hundreds of thousands of results but using UNION it only displays one of each, right? Still, it takes about 10 secunds or more to load the page.

Comment: @Kev I am not sure how often your data is updated but have you ever thought about running a scheduled task to build the HTML code once per hour and simply include the contents in your PHP page? This is known as caching. `echo file_get_contents('/path/to/your/cached/file/locations.html');`

Comment: I guess that's the way to go if I don't find another option. Have you read my other reply in this post? Please check and reply to it if you have any idea on how to make it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kev Yes, I've read it but I am not sure how to make it work. Overall, I highly recommend going the caching route because it is going to save you development time and is the best way to avoid slowness for users.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `location2` as `location`, '2' as `number` FROM `properties` WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 AND `country` = 'spain' union SELECT `location3` as `location`, '3' as `number` FROM `properties` WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 AND `location2` = 'spain' union SELECT `location4` as `location`, '4' as `number` FROM `properties` WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 AND `location3` = 'spain' union SELECT `location5` as `location`, '5' as `number` FROM `properties` WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 AND `location4` = 'spain' union SELECT `location6` as `location`, '6' as `number` FROM `properties` WHERE `price_from` BETWEEN 0 AND 999999 AND `location5` = 'spain'
```

This being the query, how can I add indexes to speed it up?

This is the actual query performed in phpmyadmin.

Showing rows 0 - 6 (7 total, Query took 6.4767 sec)

This is the same query but I am using UNION ALL to display all the results:

Showing rows 0 - 29 (23074 total, Query took 4.0590 sec)

I desperately need something to speed up this query!